# React.js Virgin: Why is my hard coded data being passed differently than data entered by user?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

This is code I collected from a video to learn react with hooks. It's supposed to create and name 3 timers from data hard coded and allow the user to create/name new timers. My code isn't exactly the same as the video because I couldn't get his to work at all.

The Problem is: I can get it to display the name for the user input timer or the hard coded timers, but not both. Right now it will display the name for the user input timer, but not the hard coded ones.

```
import Timer from './timer'
import { useState } from 'react'



const TimerManager = () => {
const [name, setName] = useState("")

    const [timerNames, setTimerNames] = useState([
        "Medication",
        "Chicken",
        "Tee"
    ])

return(
    <div>
    <form onSubmit={(e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        const copyOfTimerNames = [...timerNames]
        copyOfTimerNames.push({name})
        setTimerNames(copyOfTimerNames)
        setName("")
    }}>
        <input value={name}
        onChange={(event) => {setName(event.target.value)}}
        />
        <button>Add New Timer</button>
    </form>
    
    {timerNames.map(timerName => (
        <Timer name={timerName} />
    ))}
    
    </div>
    );
}

export default TimerManager
```

No real changes to except the use of e.preventDefault() instead of event.preventDefault()

```
import React from 'react'
import { useState, useEffect } from "react"



const Timer = ({name}) =>{
    const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState('60');
    const [isCountdownRunning, setIsCountdownRunning] = useState(false)
    const [shouldAlert, setShouldAlert] = useState(false)
    
     

    console.log("Timer.render seconds", seconds)
    console.log("name", name)

    const secondsLeft = parseInt(seconds)
    useEffect(() =>{
        if(isCountdownRunning && secondsLeft > 0){
        setTimeout(() =>{
            setSeconds(secondsLeft - 1)
        }, 1000)
    } else {
        setIsCountdownRunning(false)
        if(shouldAlert){
           alert(`The ${name.name} Timer is done!`)
           setShouldAlert(false)
        }
    }
    },[ isCountdownRunning, secondsLeft])


    return(
        <div className="Timer">
         This is the {name.name}
        <input disabled={isCountdownRunning}
            value={seconds}
            onChange={(event) => {setSeconds(event.target.value)}}
            type="number"
        ></input>
        <button
            onClick={() => { setShouldAlert(true)
                setIsCountdownRunning(true)
                }}>
                Start Countdown
        </button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Timer
```

In timer.js if I used just ${name} the code would crash when I created a new timer and it would show [Object object] in the alert, but it would display the names of the hard coded timers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is when you are pushing in user entered names you are creating objects versus just pushing the string literal.

```
copyOfTimerNames.push({ name }) // <-- i.e. { name: "Bill" }
```

Solution: just push in the entered value.

```
<form onSubmit={(e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const copyOfTimerNames = [...timerNames];
  copyOfTimerNames.push(name); // <-- push string, i.e. "Bill"
  setTimerNames(copyOfTimerNames);
  setName("");
}}>
```

Even better, use functional state update and array concatenation. Here `names` is the current state, and it is spread into a new array with the new `name` appended at the end. Cleaner and more succinct code.

```
<form onSubmit={(e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  setTimerNames(names => [...names, name]);
  setName("");
}}>
```

Comment: Thanks, Drew Reese. I thought the way the video was using the copy of the array was a bit over complicated. He may have had something else in mind, but your second solution worked

Answer (score 0):

Your initial state is array of strings. And in your `onSubmit` you're updating your state with an object.
This is supposed to be a string.

```
// WRONG
copyOfTimerNames.push({name})

// RIGHT
copyOfTimerNames.push(name)
```

Comment: Thanks Prateek Thapa. I knew it was something like that.

Comment: Yeah, That did it